# How to redirect all the results from multiple findstr commands to same file using batchfile

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am using findstr command to filter a file based on string and redirecting that output to seperate file.

```
findstr /C:"C=EODRevaluationProcess  Temp table:TMP_EOD_REVAL_DATA" "C:\Users\Desktop\abc.txt" > C:\Users\Desktop\xyz.txt
pause
findstr /C:"sendSPPJMSMessage><Finished publishing [0] messages" "C:\Users\Desktop\abc.txt" > "C:\Users\Desktop\xyz.txt" 
pause
findstr /C:"POS_HOURLY_DATA : actualTable : POS_HOURLY_DATA_" "C:\Users\Desktop\abc.txt" > "C:\Users\Desktop\xyz.txt"
```

I want all the filtered lines to be saved in same file xyz.
But only output of first findstr command is saving in xyz.

Can anyone please suggest any idea

Thank you.

Comment: Change `>` to `>>` except for the first command...

Comment: ... see [here](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) for why.

Comment: Since you are overwriting the intermediate results, only the **last** output will be retained, not the first. Alternatively you could use parentheses enclosing all the findstr and use a single redirection to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting the output to a file using the `>` operator which will create the file if it doesn't exist and replace its contents with the output.

If you want to append to the file, rather than replacing its contents, you can use the `>>` operator.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to run `FindStr` three times against the same file. Putting all the search strings in a single command would also prevent your overwrite issue.

```bat
@FindStr /I^
 /C:"some string"^
 /C:"another string"^
 /C:"and a bigger string"^
 "source.txt" > "output.txt"
```

*You'll note that I have used carets, `^`, to escape the line returns so that your strings are easier to maintain, (each to their own line)*

Comment: there might be a difference in how the lines are sorted (might or might not be an issue for OP)

Comment: @Stephan, I've changed the example strings to hopefully lessen any specific ordering suggestion.